# Cognos calculating work days between two days

Tags: calendar, cognos-8

In a package, I have two namespaces with a structure as below:

```
NamespaceA -> work_id, start_date, end_date 
NamespaceB -> calender_date, is_holiday
```

I want to calculate the number of working days between `start_date` and `end_date` for each `work_id`.

I tried to create a new data item with an expression as below:

```
= 
[calender_date] between [start_date] and [end_date] 
and 
is_holiday = 'N' 
=
```

The above expression returns true or false, meaning whether there are any working days between the two given days.

But what I wanted is the number of working days between the two given dates. I tried to use a count with the above and it did not work.

Could you please let me know how I can change the above expression to yield a count or any other ways I can get the required result (that is, number of working days between two given dates for each work_id using the above namespaces).

Answer (score 0):

To Calculate Working days Between two dates, you should need to use DIFFDATE Function and in Where Clause put your Condition...is this case you will get your required Working days between two working days.

For Example:

SELECT DATEDIFF(day,'start_date','end_date') AS WorkingDays
FROM NamespaceA a

INNER JOIN NamespaceB b
ON b.calender_date BETWEEN a.start_date AND a.end_date

WHERE
b.[calender_date] between a.[start_date] and a.[end_date] 
and b.is_holiday = 'N'